# Applescript or Shell rename a file?

Tags: applescript, command-line, macos

The following is the code I have, however, it doesn't let me choose the extension I want to save it as. How can I save the file as a ".plist" ?

```
do shell script "echo '{ Filter = { Bundles = ( \"'" & proj & "'\" ); }; }' >> ~/Desktop/gametocheat/" & proj & " "
```

Comment: Just add .plist at the end of the file name. Though what you have here is not plist file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a tool that can write a plist such as `defaults`.

```
defaults write ~/Desktop/gametocheat/my.cheat.preference '{ "Filter" = { "Bundles" = (foo); }; }';
```